# Axis/Scale with multiple quantitative (but non-contiguous) domains

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to have an axis with multiple non-contiguous quantitative domains. For example, an axis for three /24 IP ranges (such as 192.168.3.0/24 and 192.168.11.0/24). One half of the axis would be dedicated to each of these three quantitative domains.

Is this possible without having two separate axes and without one overlarge continuous domain (e.g. 192.168.2.0 to 192.168.11.0) in which most of the axis is taken up by the empty space of the other IP ranges in the domain that I am not interested in (e.g. 192.168.4.0/24 throgh 192.168.10.0/24)?

I've thought  about an ordinal scale where I add every single IP address in the three IP ranges to the domain, but this seems inefficient.

I've also considered a threshold scale, but I need the range to map to different points for each IP address, not just one point for each IP range.

Comment: Have you tried polylinear scales? https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#linear_domain

Comment: @Oleg that seems to be working, but all of the tick labels are off.
I'm doing something like this:

Comment: You need to apply the same scale to the axis as well.

Comment: @Oleg thanks for the tip, I posted my solution as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Using polylinear scales seems to do the trick.

```
scale.domain([dot2num("192.168.3.0"),dot2num("192.168.3.255"),dot2num("192.168.11.0"),dot2num("192.168.11.255")])
     .range([0,width/2,width/2+5,width]);
axis.scale(scale)
    .tickValues([
                    dot2num("192.168.3.0"),
                    dot2num("192.168.3.128"),
                    dot2num("192.168.3.255"),
                    dot2num("192.168.11.0"),
                    dot2num("192.168.11.128"),
                    dot2num("192.168.11.255")
                ]);
```